# How to handle change of checkbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have some code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="value" />
<label for="chk">Value </label>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="But1" value="set value" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="But2" value="read checked" />
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Ready ...");
    registerHandlers();

    function registerHandlers() {
        $('#But1').click(function () {
            $('#chk').prop('checked', !$('#chk').is(':checked'));
        });
        $('#But2').click(function () {
            var chk1 = $('#chk').is(':checked');
            console.log("Value : " + chk1);
        });

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            var name = $(this).val();
            var check = $(this).prop('checked');
            console.log("Change: " + name + " to " + check);
        });
    }
});
```

How to handle change of checkbox using jQuery ?
I need to put the handler to change any checkboxes checked.

[update]

There is a checkbox and a few buttons. 
Each button can change check box. 
How to catch an event changing the checkbox?

**[Update]**

I need handle change checkbox in this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoxgeforce/JCeNF/).
When I click on the box the message "OK" button is not shown.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem? What is supposed to happen when a checkbox is changed?

Comment: What's the problem? This code appears to work just fine

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? You already have $('input[type="checkbox"]').change handler, whats wrong ?

Comment: If you change the button checkbox change events do not occur

Comment: FYI; `$('#chk').prop('checked')` returns a boolean rather then the value of the attribute. See http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: There is a checkbox and a few buttons. Each button can change check box. How to catch an event changing the checkbox?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {

        // do stuff here. It will fire on any checkbox change

});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/s6fe9/

Comment: ...and `this.checked` is very useful to determine wether the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Is it possible to register multiple handlers?

Comment: Is this still recommended in 2015?

Comment: It doesn't look like API has been changed, so yes.

Comment: this needs to be inside of $(document).ready(function ()... for me, is that correct?

Comment: It can be there

Answer (score 76):

You can use Id of the field as well

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //'checked' event code
      return;
   }
   //'unchecked' event code
});
```

Answer (score 18):

Hope, this would be of some help.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        //do the stuff that you would do when 'checked'

        return;
    }
    //Here do the stuff you want to do when 'unchecked'
});
```

Comment: as of jQuery 1.6, better to use $(this).prop("checked"), as it will change dynamically with the actual state of the checkbox.

Comment: .attr("checked") isn't correct, because it isn't updated as the user clicks. I confirm @hrabinowitz's comment.

Answer (score 11):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() { 

    if (this.checked) {

      //do your stuff

     }
});
```

Comment: Please check your own code works before posting. There is a glaring issue with your selectors...

Comment: live() is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#myForm').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    this.checked ? this.value = 'apple' : this.value = 'pineapple';
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer: code-only solutions are more likely to get deleted, because they don't explain, just fix (if any).

Comment: Sorry @rekaszeru I'll do it better next time

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me removeProp is not working properly in Chrome :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3umpa3jv/)

```
        $('#badBut1').click(function () {
        checkit('Before');
        if( $('#chk').prop('checked') )
        {
          $('#chk').removeProp('checked');
        }else{
            $('#chk').prop('checked', true);
        }
        checkit('After');
    });
    $('#But1').click(function () {
        checkit('Before');
        if( $('#chk').prop('checked') )
        {
          $('#chk').removeClass('checked').prop('checked',false);
        }else{
            $('#chk').addClass('checked').prop('checked', true);
        }
        checkit('After');
    });

    $('#But2').click(function () {
        var chk1 = $('#chk').is(':checked');
        console.log("Value : " + chk1);
    });

    $('#chk').on( 'change',function () {
        checkit('Result');
    });
    function checkit(moment) {
        var chk1 = $('#chk').is(':checked');
        console.log(moment+", value = " + chk1);
    };
```

Comment: How to toggle a checkbox without event (from the outside) : http://jsfiddle.net/k91k0sLu/1/

Answer (score 0):

get radio value by **name**

```
  $('input').on('className', function(event){
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
        if($(this).attr('name') == "worker")
            {
                resetAll();                 
            }
    });
```