# Select all checkbox in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following function to select/Deselect all checkbox.

```
$(function () {
        $("#selectall").click(function () {           
            $('.Employee').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $(".Employee").click(function () {
            if ($(".Employee").length == $(".Employee:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
            }

        });
    });
```

Its working properly but i am able to select/deselect all for first time on page load, for second time i need to reload the page.Means its not giving multiple time select/deselect functionality.

Comment: Can you setup a Fiddle here? http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What's your ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML?

Comment: please give us your HTML structure also . Would be a much help !!

Comment: You should then make a function for refreshing? Look at this page for your .attr(); wich is the problem. 
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You need to use `.change()` jquery function as answered on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180087/how-to-handle-change-of-checkbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you need to work off of the `.prop()` method.  This reads the javascript `checked` property.  Using the HTML `checked` attribute works for the first instance but fails for the rest.  Next, you need to modify your logic just a little.  I've included an example.  Observe the javascript functions.  Lastly, you should be using the `change` method or preferably the `.on('change', function(){ ... })`, but I'll keep my example closer to your original post.

```js
$(function () {
        $("#selectall").change(function () {
            $('.Employee').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $(".Employee").change(function () {
            if ($(".Employee").length == $(".Employee:checked").length) {
                $('#selectall').prop('checked', this.checked);
            } else {
                $('#selectall').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>test 1: <input type="checkbox" class="Employee"></label>
  <label>test 2: <input type="checkbox" class="Employee"></label>
  <label>test 3: <input type="checkbox" class="Employee"></label>
  <label>test 4: <input type="checkbox" class="Employee"></label>
  <label>test 5: <input type="checkbox" class="Employee"></label>
</div>

<label>Select All: <input id="selectall" type="checkbox"></label>
```