# jQuery Checkbox Action when Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox which when selected, should show table rows, and when unchecked, should hide the rows .. Below is my code:

```
        <tr class='row New Request' style="display:none">
            <td>Storage</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="storage" value="storage"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='row New Request' style="display:none">
            <td>Network Infrastructure</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="network" name="network" value="network"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='subrow network' style="display:none">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="Wireless" name="Wireless" value="Wireless Connection">Wireless Connection</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="LAN" name="LAN" value="LAN Connection">LAN Connection</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='row New Request' style="display:none">
            <td>Security Infrastructure</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="security" value="security"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='row New Request' style="display:none">
            <td>New Requset 4</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

And for the jQuery, here it is:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function changeVal() {
            $('#myHeader').html(this.name);
            $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.row').hide();
            $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.subrow').hide();
            $('.'+this.value).show();
            var tempText = "";
            switch(this.value)
            {
                case "Inquiry":
                    tempText="Send Inquiry";
                    break;
                case "Feedback":
                    tempText="Send Feedback";
                    break;
                case "Complain":
                    tempText="File Complain";
                    break;
                case "Request":
                    tempText="New Request";
                    break;
            }
            $('#myHeader').html(tempText).toggle(this.value != 'default');
        }

        $(function(){
            $('#contactSelect').change(changeVal);
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function changeValSub() {
            $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.subrow').hide();
            //$('.'+this.value).show();
            alert($(this).select() == false);
            if($(this).select() == false)
                $('.'+this.value).hide();
            else
                $('.'+this.value).show();
        }

        $(function(){
            $('#network').change(changeValSub);
        });
    </script>
```

This is a part of complete table that shows/hides rows depending on the dropdown and the checkboxes ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle change of checkbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180087/how-to-handle-change-of-checkbox-using-jquery).

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle and I will do it for you, it is really simple.

Comment: not helping .. I need to show/hide the rows based on the checkbox selection .. Currently, the rows are shown, and not hidden when unchecking the checkbox

Comment: @Chris: Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/g8vukbpk/

Comment: @Chris: Can you also comment the update that you will make?

Comment: Yes, let me just quickly have a look at what you need again

Comment: @sikas can you come on the chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript so I can talk to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chatroom. We made some fixes like adding the id to the security checkbox and also removing the callback function and using toggle instead.

Here is the final jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g8vukbpk/8/

```
.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.is(':checked')` instead of `$.select()`. i.e.

```
function changeValSub() {
  $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.subrow').hide();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.'+this.value).show();
  }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joeycakes/g8vukbpk/6/)